# Using IPTables to forward local requests on one port to a remote server on another port

Tags: iptables, docker

I have an application in a Docker container. I have the DB in another Docker container. The DB container has an exposed port of 49155. The application requires that the database be exposed on port 3306 and I can't change that thanks to IonCube obfuscation. So, I can point my application to the database container just fine, but the application can't find the DB (wrong port).

My initial solution was to us IPTables to forward local requests on port 3306 to the remote container on port 49155 using:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --src 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --destination 192.168.200.212 --to-ports 49155
```

Still not working. Any thoughts?

### EDIT

From application server tried:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dst 192.168.200.212 --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 49155
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.212:49155
```

Still no luck. Also ran `nmap -p 3306 -sT 192.168.200.212` which showed 3306 as closed from the perspective of the application server.

Comment: your src won't be 127.0.0.1 it will be the IP of the interface being used ... unless the DB is on the same host

Answer (score 1):

If we refer to the [NetFilter packet flow diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Diagrama_linux_netfilter_iptables.gif), we can see that only the **OUTPUT** and **POSTROUTING** chains will be referred for packets generated by Local Processes.

So, I'd try these lines:

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dst 192.168.200.212 --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.212:49155
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst 192.168.200.212 --dport 3306 -j MASQUERADE
```

The first rule 'replaces' the destination IP:Port; the second rule 'replaces' the source IP:Port.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dst 192.168.200.212 --dport 80 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 49155
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try iptables on the DB server instead, i.e.

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 49155

Comment: The problem is that the only exposed port on the DB server is 49155, so even if I changed it on the DB server, the application server wouldn't have access to 3306.

Comment: Try on application side : iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.212:49155

Answer (score 0):

I would use DNAT for port forwarding at application server side, to forward port 3306 to port 49155 :

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -–dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 192.168.200.212:49155`

To setup port forwarding at Database server side i would use :

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 49155`

In both case `--src 127.0.0.1` has nothing to do here.

If you want to filter on source ip, `--src` should be the application server ip address in both case.

Comment: I'd have to do it from the application server side since I don't control the DB side. The DB accepts requests on 49155. I tried your solution and still no connection. I ran `nmap -p 3306 -sT 192.168.200.212` and it is showing port 3306 as closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. My working solution (based on https://serverfault.com/a/566852/475571):

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dst 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.200.212:49155
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst 192.168.200.212 --dport 49155 -j MASQUERADE
```